# How to Compare two registers and perform action if greater than without branching in ARM

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, arm, branchless

I am trying to compare two registers r5 and r6 which I know I can do with

```
CMP R7, R5
```

What I am trying to do is

if R7 > 1 then `ADD R8, R8, #1` Without branching as I will be using this multiple times in different sections of the code

I know BGT will branch if greater than, or if its possible to return to previous position after branching to add to count?

Comment: Please clarify your question. "cmp r7, r5, r6" is not a valid opcode. Do you wan to run the add if r5>r6 or if r7>1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ARM instructions [are defined as OP{cond}](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihiddid.html), this means you can make the execution of this instruction depend on a condition:

```
cmp r5, r7
addgt r8, r8, #1 //increments r8 if r5 is greater than r7
mov r1, r0 //executes in any case
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know I can modify ADD to add if greater than. Will this work with most instructions as well?

Comment: Most ARM instructions, but not all. Check ARM infocenter (linked in my answer) to be sure.